# 2D map embedded in a higher dimensional space with weird domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am getting confused about something.

Let us say we have 2D vector space and a bijective transformation on that vector space, call it $M$.

Normally one would choose to represent this in 2D eculidean coordiantes. But I can just embed the 2D plane into some randomly oriented plane in 3D. In 2D $M$ is represented as a 2x2 matrix but in 3D it is represented by a 3x3 matrix. However it is the same transformation, we just changed the coordinate system. However under its 3D representation $M$ doesn't exclusively transform vectors in the spefied domain, ti could in theory transform any vector in the ambient 3D eculidean space.

This leads me to multiple questions. First, is the determinant of both $M_2$ and $M_3$ the same? How do the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M_2$ relate to those of $M_3$?

Comment: M2 to M3 is like Quebec to Canada; why would their determinants be the same, or related at all? (Eigenvalues are another story.)

Comment: The determinants should be related because it is the exact same transformation. In one case it is embedded in 2D and the other 3D. But the underlying transformation is the same so I would assume some properties carry from one to the other.

Comment: They can't be the same, for they act on different spaces. Imagine a man with two hands, and then a man with three hands; are they the same? M2 has two eigenvalues, M3 has 3, of which two are indeed the same as in M2, and the third can be anything.

Comment: > , of which two are indeed the same as in M2

See this is part of the answer to my question, now I know that the eigenvalues of M3 relate to those of M2 in that 2 are shared between them, this is very useful. Thank you.